# FTDI breakout connection

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, ftdi

I have been successfully programming UNO boards. I wanted to transfer the project to a Pro Mini. I am using a FTDI breakout. It wouldn't show the device port. I found the device driver I was using was supplied by MatterControl. So I updated the driver from FTDI.

When I connected it I see the port available, but cannot program it. I get

```
not in sync: resp=0x01 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I checked in the device manager and see "USB Serial Port (COM5)" and properties shows "This device is working properly." the provider is FTDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can come from a number of sources and you'll find this is a common question on arduino.stackexchange. The most likely reasons are:

- If the board wasn't reset, the bootloader didn't run;
- Rx & Tx connections between the FTDI and the board may be reversed;
- Avrdude may be using a different baud rate than the bootloader expects. 57600 baud used to be standard for Atmega328p bootloaders. More recent firmware is using 115200 baud. I've been bitten by this one regularly; my chips have older bootloaders and one of my PCs has a very recent Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I made the board using the great tutorial by Nick Gammon  for the minimum Arduino board. I got the boot loader to load using Nick's tutorial and then spent a few evenings trying to use FTDI to upload sketches but could not get it to work. In the end, using various bits of inforamtion I found on the web, I made sure the reset signal was coming from the the FTDI (going to low) and then checked the settings of the FTDI and tried to make some changes. I found that the settings in my photos work. Mainly the bit rate 115200 and the latency (m/secs) time to 5 m/secs. The wires from FTDI starting from the top in looking at photo - brown (ground to ground), red (vcc to vcc) orange (tx to rx), Yellow (rx to tx), the other separate orange (was better I used another colour!) is from RTS to reset.
I selected Arduino uno as board and (in my case) COM 10. For me it ow works. I don't know if I would make many of these boars though because of the time and effort. However, itwas a good expeiance and I learnt a great deal. Particularly from Nick Gammon. Thanks Nick!

[image: connections]

[image: settings]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by changing "set RTS on close" in the device manager properties as stated here
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87955/80377